# Having VERY difficult time trying to print any color at all on a picture (16.04)

Tags: 16.04, printing

Let me tell you first of all I'm a tenderfoot when it comes to Ubuntu.  So anyways I recently had my bike stolen and a friend of mine has done wonderful job creating a flyer.  This flyer has some color on it and some detail that can't be missed.  I've been struggling for the last couple of hours trying to get ANY color at all on my printed page.  I can manage to print some kind of black and white page, but that's it.  I do the print preview,so glad I found it, the print preview shows a page with color and good detail, but when I press print, it comes out in this not so good b&w image.  I even took my old color cartridge.  I installed a new cartridge in.

What am I doing wrong here?  At this point I would consider it a screaming success if I could get a could of color spots on my print out.

I'm using the printer setup that came with Ubuntu.  I'm looking at the different options and it seems that just about all the options are setup for color and with fine definition.  If there was a way to load up my setting for you, please let me know.  If I got to describe each setting, ok, will do!  Just let me know which ones you want.

Thanks for reading this and let me know if I missed some info.

Comment: What is the model number of your printer? What is your Ubuntu version? What is the name of the program you are using to create and print your flyer? What is it's version number?

Comment: Sorry just saw 16.04 was in your title not in body or tags.

Comment: It's a Cannon MX330 USB connected.   It shows up on my OS that it's there and it's my only printer.  I can print b&w images too.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, try googling your problem. I searched

> Cannon MX330 USB ubuntu

And found [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/12/canon-driver-scangear-mp-ubuntu-14-04/). First, check to see if your printer is on the compatibility list (in your case, it is). Since yours is, follow the steps below to install drivers for your printer (Note below steps came from above site.)

- To get started, open terminal, and run the following:

  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inameiname/stable`

  This will add the PPA repository into your system.
- After that, open Synaptic Package Manager from the Unity Dash. If you don’t find it, search for and install it from Ubuntu Software Center. Click the Reload button to refresh your system cache.
- In Quick filter box, type in cnijfilter.
- Select a package in the result list that matches your device. Right-click on the package and select “Mark for Installation.”
- Finally click on the “Apply” button to install the driver.

Comment: For reference, I did actually use google to see if I could find an answer to my problem.  As a matter of fact, I searched "16.04 canon printer problems" and 3 out of the four top hits I visited already.  As a matter of fact, I visited the page you posted!  If you look at the page, it doesn't necessarily shouts out "this is ur page homie!"  I had no clue that was the page that would work.  I guess I should have stated at the beginning that I'm new to using Ubuntu.  My bad!  Oh yeah........... this is my 3rd comment here.  (learning that hitting the enter key gets my comment posted!  Sweet!)